# how to use eval in html angularjs expression?

Tags: html, angularjs

I have an array

```
$scope.arr = [
  {
   description : 'state'
  },
  {
   description : 'country'
  }
]
$scope.state=['a','b'] 
$scope.country=['1','2']
```

I'am repeating this arr in an directive

```
<div ng-repeat="data in arr">
 <dynamic-directive resonse="data.description"></dynamic-directive>
```

here  "data.description" is $scop.state in first cycle where i want to send $scope.state=['a','b'] but im sending the string "state"

Comment: can you share code for directive.. Generally you should ng-model and read it in directive